# How to access endpoints from an ACR deployed to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I deployed a sample rest web service in ACR, and later deployed to Azure App Service. Initially when I deployed the application in wildfly server, it can be access via ***{server-url}/{port}/home*** as my default sample request mapping url.

However, when I dockerized the application and push to ACR and finally deployed to Wildfly Azure App Service, I don't know how to access the ***/home*** endpoint since the App service will typically give you a default public url for your app.

Can someone help me how to access endpoints from your controller when it is deployed to App Service. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to check this [Run Wildfly on App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/01/31/Wildfly-on-App-Service.html) and this [Azure Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-wildfly#readme).

Comment: Let me try to look at this one. Thank you for the Link